# Unable to set grant priviladge in mysql

Tags: mysql, privileges

I am trying to set grant privilege by this:

```
GRANT SUPER ON db_name.* TO user@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

but all time I am getting this error

> "Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)".
>   I know it's very common issue, I have searched it a lot but didn't get any solution. Please help me where I am doing wrong.

Comment: Here is your answer https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/63404/how-to-grant-super-privilege-to-the-user

Comment: I don't have root user. I processed all things that i can. Here I think the only problem is I am getting all time this error "ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' to database 'database_name"

Answer (score 0):

please try this, it will be helpful to you ..

`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON db_name.* TO 'username'@'host' identified by 'password';`

after this,

```
flush privileges;
```